# Start recounting chapters in each part

Tags: chapters, memoir

I am trying to create a booklet and this booklet contains four parts. Every part has some chapters, but memoir does not start recounting every chapter after a new part has started.

So I am getting this:

Part I

1. Chapter
2. Chapter
3. Chapter

Part II
4. Chapter
5. Chapter

But I want this:

Part I

1. Chapter
2. Chapter
3. Chapter

Part II

1. Chapter
2. Chapter

How do I get this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}` should do.

Comment: Don't. But if you *really* want it, add `\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}` to your document preamble.

Comment: Why do you say don't?
Thanks for the suggestion b.t.w.

Comment: Because it'll get confusing if you say "look at chapter 1" (which 1 is 1?)

Comment: That might be true. I am going to reconsider this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Reconsider it. However, you can do it and just comment the relevant line when you change your mind about it. I don't recommend doing it, because cross references will become awkward:

> As we saw in chapter 1 of part II, something different happens with respect to what we saw in chapter 2 of part I.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%%% reset the chapter counter when a new part starts
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\begin{document}

\part{Title}

\chapter{Title}

\chapter{Title}

\part{Title}

\chapter{Title}

\chapter{Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Production note.** In order to make the image, I used the `oneside` option and `geometry` with the `a6paper` option, but omitted that in the code above.